# PostgreSQL LEFT JOIN not working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have 2 tables:

```
T1 (id, flag1)
T2 (id, amount, date, flag2, t1_id);
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT T1.id, ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(T2.amount), 0), 2) AS spent_amount
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id
WHERE T2.date <= '2014-01-01' AND T2.flag2 = 't' AND T1.flag1 = 't'
GROUP BY T1.id
```

The problem is that I want to have a row in the result such as: `id = 123, spent_amount = 0` in case where I have an entrance in `T1`, but it has no connected rows in `T2`.

Comment: I do not know about postgresql, but in SQL Server you would have to put what is limiting T2 from your where to your join: `LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id AND T2.date <= '2014-01-01' AND T2.flag2 = 't' WHERE T1.flag1 = 't'`

Comment: The `WHERE` clause negates the `LEFT JOIN` because it excludes any `NULL` values. Either move it into the `ON` clause or use a `COALESCE` on the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Having a WHERE clause on your T2 it will filter out all NULLS:

```
SELECT T1.id, ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(T2.amount), 0), 2) AS spent_amount 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 
    ON T2.t1_id = T1.id 
    AND T2.date <= '2014-01-01' 
    AND T2.flag2 = 't' 
WHERE T1.flag1 = 't'
```